# How can I choose grandchild fields based on url parameter in django DetailView

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm writing a django application that deals with audio recordings.

So we have a class setup something like this:

```
class Session
   #... fields that belong to the whole Session ... #

class Channel
   session = models.ForeignKey(Session, related_name='channels')

class Annotation
   channel = models.ForeignKey(Channel, related_name='annotations') 
   type = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Event
   annotation = models.ForeignKey(Annotation, related_name='events')
   start = models.DateTimeField()
   end = models.DateTimeField()
```

So, each Session has multiple audio Channels. Each Channel can have multiple Annotations of different types, and each Annotation has many events that line up with the audio in each channel.

Now I want to be able to visit a url of something like `/<session_slug>/<annotation_type>` and have the view show, for all channels, only the events for the annotation of the type in the url.

At present I am using a `DetailView` for the Session, and I'd like the structure of the html template to look something like this:

```
{% for channel in session %}
...
{% with annotation = somehow choose the correct annotation %}
{% for event in annotation %}
... display the event ...
{% end for %}
{% end with %}
...
{% end for %}
```

Obviously the problem is getting the correct annotation object into the template.

What is the best way to deal with this sort of problem in django?

Answer (score 0):

If you're showing multiple annotations, I'd say a ListView would be more appropriate than a DetailView. You could then override `get_queryset` to filter the annotations by session:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Annotation.objects.filter(channel__session__slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
```

Comment: I'm not sure about that solution, because the page is mostly about the   Session, and the list of events in the annotations is just a small part. I could have a Session object, and a list of annotations separate in the context I guess, but I really wanted the template designer to be able to drill down through Sessions and Channel, and into Events through the selected Annotation without having to access anything outside of the object structure.